# Pop multiple values atomically from a Redis FIFO queue

Tags: redis, queue, fifo

I've setup a first-in, first-out (FIFO) queue in Redis with LISTs using RPUSH/LPUSH and RPOP/LPOP, how can I atomically pop multiple items from the queue at once? If LISTs and the commands mention doesn't support it, what should I use instead?

Answer (score 2):

There is no command that performs multiple pops, but you can either wrap these in a [transaction](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) or with a [Lua script](https://redis.io/commands/eval).

Answer (score 2):

Redis [transactions](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) are guaranteed to be atomic and can thus be used to first get the items using [`LRANGE`](https://redis.io/commands/lrange) and then delete them using [`LTRIM`](https://redis.io/commands/ltrim):

```
> RPUSH l 1 2 3 4 5
LRANGE mylist 0 -1
> MULTI
OK
> LRANGE l 0 1
QUEUED
> LTRIM l 2 -1
QUEUED
> EXEC
1) 1) "1"
   2) "2"
2) OK
> LRANGE l 0 -1
1) "3"
2) "4"
3) "5"
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 6.2.0, [LPOP](https://redis.io/commands/lpop/) and [RPOP](https://redis.io/commands/rpop/) now support a `count` argument.